# Expression in PyQGIS does not work

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, expression

Now I am trying to create a field column by using Expression on PyQGIS. The following code allows me to create a column. But, I can't get any values on "budgets_Budgets_county" on the "budgets" column (though I have 0 on this column). Note that the "budgets_Budgets_county" column is string. And, if I use Field calculator and use expression 'CASE...END', I can get values I want. But, I can't get these values if I use PyQGIS. Where is wrong?

```
county = QgsVectorLayer('[path]/county.json',
                        'county', 
                        'ogr')

# Replicating 
feats = [feat for feat in county.getFeatures()]

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", 
                           "mem_layer", 
                           "memory")

mem_layer_data = mem_layer.dataProvider()
attr = county.dataProvider().fields().toList()
mem_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
mem_layer.updateFields()
mem_layer_data.addFeatures(feats)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

# Replicating 

with edit(mem_layer):
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('("STATE"=\'02\')or("STATE"=\'15\')or("STATE"=\'72\')')
    request.setSubsetOfAttributes([])
    request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
    for f in mem_layer.getFeatures(request):
        mem_layer.deleteFeature(f.id())

pv = mem_layer.dataProvider()
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('fips', QVariant.String)])
mem_layer.updateFields()
expression = QgsExpression('"STATE"+"COUNTY"')
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(\
QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(mem_layer))
with edit(mem_layer):
    for f in mem_layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['fips'] = expression.evaluate(context)
        mem_layer.updateFeature(f)

# Table data

budgets = QgsVectorLayer('[path]/county_budgets.csv',
                        'budgets', 
                        'ogr')
# Join 

shpField='fips'
csvField='fips'
joinObject = QgsVectorLayerJoinInfo()
joinObject.setJoinFieldName(csvField)
joinObject.setTargetFieldName(shpField)
joinObject.setJoinLayerId(budgets.id())
joinObject.setUsingMemoryCache(True)
joinObject.setJoinLayer(budgets)
mem_layer.addJoin(joinObject)

# Construct budget integer column 

pv = mem_layer.dataProvider()
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('budgets', QVariant.Int)])
mem_layer.updateFields()
expression = QgsExpression('CASE WHEN "budgets_Budgets_county" IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE "budgets_Budgets_county" END')
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(mem_layer))
with edit(mem_layer):
    for f in mem_layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['budgets'] = expression.evaluate(context)
        mem_layer.updateFeature(f)
```

Comment: Your code is working for me with the line `mem_layer=iface.activeLayer()` added on top. How do you create `mem_layer` variable?

Comment: I just updated the code. I use json and copy them to a memory to protect the original file. I use ```mem_layer=iface.activeLayer()```. But, it does not work.